# Can I turn off further comments on a single page?

Tags: comments

I have a blog post with comments on. I want to stop all people posting any further comments but keep the ones that are currently there. How do I do that? Using Wordpress 3.5.1

Comment: close it only for a single post or all posts?

Comment: Just for a single post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the setting in the **Discussion** post meta box:

[image: Discussion meta box with comments disabled]

*(If you can't see this meta box on your post edit screen, go to the Screen Options tab and check the box next to 'Discussion')*

Changing this setting **will not delete existing comments**. It will just turn off the ability to comment as long as the setting is disabled. It only applies to the post you change the setting for.